# Is it possible to run a function everyday with time-driven trigger without having an active spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that updates cells and sends emails when called. I would like to run it everyday without having to open the spreadsheet (the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method).

So I tried to call it using server side method `openById()`. But the function doesn't fire when the spreadsheet is not open.

Is there a way to run it with the spreadsheet closed?

Here is the code:

```
function updateNote() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MySpreadsheetID");
//do things
};`

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
// Trigger fonction everyday at 10.35am   
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateNote')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(10)
      .nearMinute(35)
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
};
```

Comment: In script editor>View> executions>shows why it failed.

Comment: It did not fire. So I can't see any executions

Comment: I know you created the trigger from code, but does the trigger show up in the trigger menu? https://blog.rudolphk.co.za/hacky-tip-use-google-sheets-to-run-scheduled-recurring-cronjobs-4259f5a41345

Comment: Make sure you've cleared all filters on the top. Also, see whether you have a trigger at Edit> Current project triggers

Comment: It's possible! Review the active triggers list. I usually prefer to create the triggers directly in the G Suite Developer Hub...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer:

*You can create an installable trigger to run every day without needing to have your Spreadsheet open.*

### Details:

Using a time-based installable trigger you can have your function run daily, though as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers):

> The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

If this is not a problem for you, then you can do this from the Apps Script Editor for your project - follow the path `Edit > Current project's triggers` which will open the triggers page for the project in a new tab.

In the bottom left, click on the `+ Add Trigger` button to bring up the `Add Trigger` modal - use hte following properties:

- Choose which function to run: `updateNote()`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `Time-driven`
- Select type of time based trigger: `Day timer`
- Select time of day: `10am to 11am`

**If running at exactly 10:35 is important to you:**

You can follow the same steps as above, but with slightly different properties:

- Choose which function to run: `createTimeDrivenTriggers()`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `Time-driven`
- Select type of time based trigger: `Day timer`
- Select time of day: `9am and 10am`

With this, you'll be creating your time-based trigger to run at 10:35 on a daily basis, always running before the trigger needs to fire.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)