# How can I reset permissions for Google Drive (Folders, subfolders and files)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to reset all Files & folders permissions to "restricted". on the entire drive.

Permissions on google drive don't cascade so removing them from parent folder won't remove them on Sub-folders & files. And I have an very large number of files and folders.

I found and outdated post with a script but the "Uiapp" function is deprecated (and someone in comment said something about it could remove some files so not really what I'm looking for)

This is the outdated post for something similar (Not working anymore) : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37592/how-do-i-reset-permissions-for-google-drive-documents-in-all-subfolders

Comment: Can I ask you about the approximate number of files and folders you want to change the permissions to "restricted"? And in your situation, the target is all files and folders under the root folder? Or, the target is all files and folders under the specific folder?

Comment: All files and folders under root folder. i'd say around 60k files and 15k folders

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have 4 questions. 1. About `"restricted"` you expect, in this case, when a file is shared with other users, how will you do? 2. When the owner of the file is not you, what will you do? 3. In your situation, how about the shared Drive? 4. In your tag, `google-apps-script` is included. In your situation, Google Apps Script is used? If it's so, can you provide your current script?

Comment: 1- `Restricted` as in "all drive is private", nothing is shared, files and folders can only be seen by the drive owner (files owner).
2- I'm the owner of every file on my drive
3- I don't care about shared drive
4- I used `google-apps-script` because from previous threads i've seen, that how people do it. There is a link in my question containing an old thread with a deprecated function. I'm also unsure if its exactly what is needed in my case.

Old script here : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37592/how-do-i-reset-permissions-for-google-drive-documents-in-all-subfolders

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the Drive API to retrieve all files, then loop through them setting the permissions to `PRIVATE`.*

#### More Information:

The trickiest part here is the number of files you have will undoubtedly mean that the script execution time will far exceed the Apps Script limits. You can however get around this by storing all file IDs initially and then looping through them, continuing where you left off on last execution.

#### Code:

As the Drive API is faster than the in-built `DriveApp`, I'll be using this in my example. Make sure to enable the Drive Advanced Service before running.

```js
function getAllFileIds() {
  const fileIds = []
  let files = Drive.Files.list({
    pageSize: 1000
  })

  while (files.nextPageToken) {
    console.log(files.nextPageToken)
    fileIds.push(...files.files.map(x => x.id))
    files = Drive.Files.list({
      pageSize: 1000,
      pageToken: files.nextPageToken
    })
  }
  fileIds.push(...files.files.map(x => x.id))

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Files List")
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, fileIds.length, 1).setValues(fileIds.map(x => [x]))
  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sheet", ss.getId())
}

function changePermissions() {
  const props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(props.getProperty("sheet")).getSheetByName("Files List")

  let ids

  const curr = parseInt(props.getProperty("index"))
  if (curr) {
    ids = sheet.getRange(curr, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - curr, 1).getValues().flat(2)
  }
  else {
    ids = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().flat(2)
  }

  ids.forEach(function(id, index) {
    try {
      console.log(id)
      DriveApp.getFileById(id).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.info(e)
    }
    props.setProperty("index", index + 1)
  })
}
```

The idea is thus:

- Run the function `getAllFileIds()`. This will:
- Use the Drive API to retrieve up to 1000 files at a time and add all their IDs to an array.
- Create a Spreadsheet to save all the IDs to.
- Save the Spreadsheet ID to the script's properties for later access.

I opted to log each `nextPageToken` so you can see it runs - I have ~16,800 files and folders in my Drive and this function took a minute or so to run.

Then, you can run the function `changePermissions()`. This will:

- Checks the script's properties for the ID of the spreadsheet and an index of how many rows have been completed
- Opens the spreadsheet
- If there is a saved `index` value, then the script starts from where it last left off
- If there is no saved `index` value, the script starts from the beginning of the list
- Loops through each file by ID and sets the Access to `PRIVATE`.
- Each time a permission is changed, the new index gets saved to the script properties.

You will have to run this multiple times. I suggest creating a time based trigger so that the function runs multiple times without the need to manually re-run. You can find the instructions for this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217606/11551468).

**NB:** Apps Script execution time limit is 6 minutes for Gmail accounts and 30 minutes for Business/Enterprise. Please bear this in mind when setting up an installable trigger so that individual script executions do not overlap.

#### References:

- [Files:list | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Class SpreadsheetApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class PropertiesService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service?hl=en)
- [Class DriveApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [Class File | Apps Script | Google Devlopers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [Enum Permission | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)
- [Enum Access | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)